# can someone help me with this code for school?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

This is my code:

```
for (Article a : articles) {
  boxNumber = magazine.getFfd().searchArticleInBox(a);
  if (boxNumber >= 3) {
    text = text + "Place box " + boxNumber + "\n";
  }   
} 
textArea.append(text);
```

It does work i get:

```
Place box 3
Place box 3
Place box 3
Place box 3
Place box 4
Place box 4
```

This is not how I want it. I hope someone can tell me how I get it only one time when the number changes, so I get:

```
Place box 3
Place box 4
```

Comment: store the last number and test to see if `doosnummer ` is the same, if not print it out and update the value of the last number

Comment: Can you use english words in your code? It makes the code more understandable for us.

Comment: @ThomasBöhm should not matter for this trivial code

Comment: is there any possibility that after 3, 4 again 3 will come ?

Answer (score 3):

Keep the last value and check against it:

```
int last = 0;
for (Artikel a : artikelen) {
    doosnummer = magazijn.getFfd().zoekArtikelInDoos(a);
    if (doosnummer >= 3) {
        if (last != doosnummer) {
            last = doosnummer;
            text = text + "Plaats doos " + doosnummer + "\n";
        }
    }
}
textArea.append(text);
```

Note that it would be more efficient to append the `String`s to a single `StringBuilder` object instead of using `String` concatenation, which keeps creating new `String` objects:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
int last = 0;
for (Artikel a : artikelen) {
    doosnummer = magazijn.getFfd().zoekArtikelInDoos(a);
    if (doosnummer >= 3) {
        if (last != doosnummer) {
            last = doosnummer;
            text.append("Plaats doos ");
            text.append(doosnummer);
            text.append("\n");
        }
    }
}
textArea.append(text.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember the old number and only print if it changed:

```
int oldDoosnummer =0;

for (Artikel a : artikelen){
            doosnummer = magazijn.getFfd().zoekArtikelInDoos(a);
            if (doosnummer >= 3 && doosnummer != oldDoosnummer){
                text = text + "Plaats doos " + doosnummer + "\n";
                oldDoosnummer = doosnummer;
            }   
        } textArea.append(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> oldOccurrenceArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Artikel a : artikelen) {
    doosnummer = magazijn.getFfd().zoekArtikelInDoos(a);

    if (doosnummer >= 3 && !oldOccurrenceArrayList.contains(doosnummer)) 
    {
        text = text + "Plaats doos " + doosnummer + "\n";
        oldOccurrenceArrayList.add(doosnummer);
    }
}
textArea.append(text);
```

You create an `ArrayList` with all the values that you already passed. This way you never get any double values.

Comment: Rather overkill isn't it?

Comment: can't catch you... ??

Comment: This one is actually better since we don't know if the list is sorted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (Artikel a : artikelen) {
      doosnummer = magazijn.getFfd().zoekArtikelInDoos(a);
      String check = "Plaats doos " + doosnummer;
      if (doosnummer >= 3 && text.contains(check)==false) {
       text = text + check + "\n";
       }   
      } 
     textArea.append(text);
```